# What is Springer's “version of record”?

Tags: publications, journals, springer

What is Springer's “version of record”? Is it the final originally published version of an article or book?

According to the answers that I received, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version of record is *the article or contribution as published including copy editing and lay out*.

<sup>Source: Peter Davidhazi (2014) "New publication cultures in the humanities: exploring the paradigm shift."</sup>

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Springer document](https://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/1672714/application/docx/Ethical%2520Policy%2520-%2520Authors%2520docx.docx)

> The "Version of Record" is defined as the final version of the Work as originally published, and as may be subsequently amended following publication in a contractually compliant manner, by or on behalf of the Publisher.